# Populating a C# TreeView with a DataTable

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a DataTable with the following sample data in it:

```
Name     ID     ParentID
A        1      0
B        2      1
C        3      2
D        4      1
E        5      4
```

I want the treeview to have the data in a hierarchical fashion:

- A

  - B

    - C
- D

  - E

Below is the code I have so far, but it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.  I am getting my source in the form of a Data Table with columns "Name", "ID", and "Parent ID"

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView)
{
        treeView.Nodes.Clear();
        DataTable myDataTable = getFolders();
                var stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
                var rootDirectory = myDataTable.Rows[0];
                var node = new TreeNode(rootDirectory["Name"].ToString()) { Tag = rootDirectory };
                stack.Push(node);

            while (stack.Count > 0)
            {
                var currentNode = stack.Pop();
                var directoryInfo = (DataRow)currentNode.Tag;

                foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
                {
                    var childDirectoryNode = new TreeNode(row["Name"].ToString()) { Tag = row };
                    currentNode.Nodes.Add(childDirectoryNode);
                    stack.Push(childDirectoryNode);

                }               
            }
            treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The code repeatedly runs over myDataTable.Rows again and again, without adjusting its size - is that intentional?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm trying to populate treeView, not myDataTable.

Comment: Yes I see that but aren't you re-adding the same items to the stack over and over?

Comment: Your infinite loop is because you're calling `Pop` just once through the loop, but you're also calling `Push` for each row in your `DataTable` so you'll never empty your stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work, but won't scale very well to a large dataset since it performs a search through both the entire dataset and tree to find the correct parent.  It uses the ID column as the Key on each TreeNode - and requires that you set a primary key on the ID column in your dataset.

```
DataRow root = myDataTable.Rows[0];
treeView.Nodes.Add(root["ID"].ToString(), root["Name"].ToString());

for (int i = 1; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow parentRow = myDataTable.Rows.Find(myDataTable.Rows[i]["ParentID"]);
    TreeNode[] parent = treeView.Nodes.Find(parentRow["ID"].ToString(), true);
    parent[0].Nodes.Add(myDataTable.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString(), myDataTable.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Definitely could use optimizations and error checking, but gets you there on small datasets.